# Using CoreData to save data across Views and sessions

Tags: iphone

I am new to IOS and coreData Framework..from past 2 days m reading tutors regarding coredata..I understood few concepts..but i am confused..can you all please suggest me good tutorials regarding coredata.
So my  second problem..I am building a application..where my first view has a text field and a search button..and an empty table..so when the user enters a search query and hit the search button..it opens a another view which gives him a list of values in a table and again when the user cliks on a specific cell he is agian taken to page which contains some values..so on this page ,I want to have a button name (xyz) which when cliked..will save that particular value in the table which is present in the first view..and similarly the process will conitnue..

So i want to know..whether coredata is necessary for my problem or any diffrent menthods are available......

Please reply..m waiting for your respones..

Regards
RRK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Data manage very well sqlite database.

You can learn on the apple developer website : 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Devpedia-CoreData/coreDataOverview.html

And there is a quite good tutorial here :
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Introduction/Introduction.html

I think core data is a very suitable solution for your problem.

Comment: No it is quite easy. Basically you create a model (xcode should create one for you). Then you export the class associated to the model, you create the static methods to instantiate your objects. There is no easier way as far as my iOS knowledge goes. If you are confortable with the TableView, you will particularly like the NSFetchResultController which allow you to fetch your core data in 10 lignes. I was new in iOS one month ago, I read the documentation, and all goes well. Good luck ;

Comment: Hey Nielsou..thanks..for encouraging...me..i am comfortable with creating the model..through the ui framework which...xcode provides..shall we go step by step in my problem applying the coredata..